# datagridview column width changed

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, column-width

I have 2 datagridview .I want to change width of a column of datagriview while I'm changing the width of a column of the other datagridview with the mouse.
I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnMinimumWidthChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnMinimumWidthChanged
    HeaderGrid.Columns(e.Column.Index).Width = e.Column.Width
End Sub
```

I edited my code by adding a mouseleave event and it works but not properly.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseLeave
    Dim c As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
    Dim h As DataGridViewColumn = HeaderGrid.Columns(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
    h.Width = c.Width
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by using another event:

```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseLeave
    If e.ColumnIndex <> -1 And HeaderGrid.ColumnCount <> 0 Then
        Dim c As DataGridViewColumn = DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)
        Dim h As DataGridViewColumn = HeaderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)
        h.Width = c.Width
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataGridView1.ColumnWidthChanged` event instead of `ColumnMinimumWidthChanged` for catching `Width` changes

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(sender As Object,
                                             e As DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnWidthChanged
    HeaderGrid.Columns(e.Column.Index).Width = e.Column.Width
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @fabio. I tried your solution but I got the error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index....In fact y headergrid is used as a filter for the second datagridview

Comment: I edited my post by adding a screenshot and the code changed.